# Print all 3-digits numers less or equal to 1234

Tags: php

I have the following task: Write PHP script that declares an number n, and then finds all 3-digit numbers that are less or equal to n and consist of unique digits. Print "No" if no such number exist.

I have this code:

```
<?php
$number = 1522;
for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    $numberLenght = strlen((string)$i);

    if ($numberLenght == 3) {
        echo $i . ' ';
    } else if ($number < 100) {
        echo "No";
    }
}
```

It's working only with numbers bigger than 100. When i change the value of $number for example 1 it's show me empty blanc, not "No"

Comment: show should look the output for, let's say, `$number = 109;` ?

Comment: When $number is 109, the result is correct: 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109

Comment: Isn't 100 wrong? It has 2 zeros so not all unique digits?

Answer (score 5):

A task like this, for learning purposes, may be best tackled by breaking it up into functions so you can more clearly see what is happening. So, for example we have these rules:

- Must be 3 digits
- Must be less than `n`
- Must consist of unique digits

So we can write 3 functions that accept the `$i` value and the `$n` value and return true/false.

```
function isThreeDigits($i) {
    if ((int) $i > 99 && (int) $i < 1000) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function isLessThanN($i, $n) {
    return (bool) ((int) $i < (int) $n);
}

function isUniqueDigits($i) {
    $parts = str_split((string) $i);
    $initialCount = count($parts);
    $uniqueCount = count(array_unique($parts));
    if ($initialCount === $uniqueCount) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Using these three functions, we can check everything:

```
$n = 1522;
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {

    if (isThreeDigits($i) && isLessThanN($i, $n) && isUniqueDigits($i)) {
        echo "MATCH: $i \n";
    } else {
        echo "NO \n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Required parameter $n is missing in function isThreeDigits

Comment: Oh yeah, that's because I changed something. If you want to learn programming, you have to learn to be able to recognize something like that and do your own debugging. I wrote that snippet here in StackOverflow, so it's not tested, but should get you almost there. See updated code.

Comment: hint: it has to do with names of variables

Comment: Still don't work correctly. Number is undefined variable.

Comment: Fixed. Yet another example of something I missed by hand typing this here in SO. And should have been fairly easy for you to spot. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php

Comment: You're not helping me anymore bro. Please next time when you try to answer me, check your solution. Again the output is not correct

Comment: @RumenPanchev For the record, StackOverflow is NOT a "write code for me website". Your question is low effort. I took time to write a simplistic answer to nudge you in the right direction. Good luck.

Comment: @RumenPanchev don't be rude. The folks answering questions are volunteers with busy lives, just like yours.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that you are using the wrong variable in this line?

```
else if ($number < 100) {
```

instead of checking if the current value ($i) is less than 100, you compare the $number (which is a static value).

Comment: Now with $number = 9, the output is: NoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNoNo100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109

Comment: what output are you trying to achieve?

for $number = 10; do you expect a single "No" or 10 "No"s?

Comment: A single "No" i expect

Comment: in this case you should not have the if clause that prints "No" inside of the loop, but outside of it. Otherwise the clause will be evaluated multiple times, resulting in multiple outputs ;)

Comment: if ($number < 100) {
        echo "No";
 } else {
  for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
     ....
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

This will work much better than what you have.

```
$number = 1522;

if($number < 100) exit('No');

for($i = 100; $i <= $number && $i < 1000; $i++){
    $t = str_split($i);
    if( count($t) == count(array_unique($t)) ) echo $i . ' ';   
}
```

That said, the answer @jeremy-harris posted is also correct and his is likely more useful as a learning tool.

This is slightly more optimized but uses the same basic principals as his solution. If this is some kind of homework assignment (which it appears to be) it is important that you understand why the above code works and that you don't just use it to complete the task.